# how to take click on custom grid view image icon?

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-gridview, onitemclicklistener

i created a custom grid view which includes the image view and text view. i want to take click on both view like click on image icon as well as text view. One more thing is that this custom grid view is implemented in fragment. I used the adapter class to set the icon and text titles which extends from Base Adapter class.
so please any one knows the way to implement this please revert back with answer..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post code of your custom gridview. @sid

Comment: Please post relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

JAVA:

```
public class MyAdapter extends  BaseAdapter
{
    /* Variable declaration */
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ArrayList<Menu> al_Menu;
    private Holder viewHolder;


    public MyAdapter (Context p_context, ArrayList<Menu> al_Menu)
    {
        super();
        this.mContext = p_context;
        this.al_Menu = al_Menu;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return al_Menu.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p_int_arg0)
    {
        return p_int_arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p_int_arg0)
    {
        return p_int_arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int p_int_pos, View p_v_convertView, ViewGroup p_vg_parent)
    {
        if (p_v_convertView == null)
        {
            /*inflate the layout */
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            p_v_convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_my, p_vg_parent, false);
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            viewHolder.iv_image =(ImageView) p_v_convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_image);
            viewHolder.tv_text =(TextView) p_v_convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            p_v_convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (Holder) p_v_convertView.getTag();
        }
        /*set text*/
        viewHolder.tv_text.setText(al_Menu.get(p_int_pos).getStrMenuName());

        /*set image*/
        viewHolder.iv_search.setImageResource(al_Menu.get(p_int_pos).getStrMenuImage());

        viewHolder.iv_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               //do here
            }
        });

        viewHolder.tv_text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //do here
            }
        });

        return p_v_convertView;
    }

    class Holder
    {
        ImageView iv_image;
        TextView tv_text;
    }
}
```

adapter_my.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/icon_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/icon_image"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where you setting the image icon to image view?

Comment: set imageview icon below viewHolder.tv_text.setText

Comment: you are directly put setOnClickListener on image below viewHolder.tv_text.setText.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both `views` in one `container` then assign `onClick` to the `container`. then set `android:duplicateParentState="true"` to enable same `onClick method` to `child views`.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```